# Can't use LeakCanary because of org.junit.Test class dependency in external libraries

Tags: java, android, leakcanary

I'm trying to use LeakCanary for finding memory leaks in my Android application. I'm using Android Studio.

When I start debugging my application I see "LeakCanary is currently disabled: test class org.junit.Test was found in classpath." message.

"org.junit.test" class came from external library.

How can I force enable LeakCanary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931705/5644761 read this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LeakCanary automatically disables itself in tests by detecting that the `org.junit.Test` is in the classpath. Unfortunately, some apps ship Junit in their app debug classpath (e.g. when using OkHttp MockWebServer). You can customize which class is used to detect tests:

```
<resources>
  <string name="leak_canary_test_class_name">assertk.Assert</string>
</resources>
```

The doc needs to be updated (tracked here: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/1968)

Comment: Sorry, but what would this customization do?

Comment: as for where to put this snippet: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/2380#issuecomment-1116156723

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to check your module build.gradle file and find "implementation" instead of "testImplementation" or "androidTestImplementation" for test dependencies. It may cause this issue.